# Xamarin.iOS app crashes on startup on iOS13 on Testflight

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, crash, ios10.3

I have tested the application on Testflight and as soon as I open it everything works correctly. The problem comes when I close the app and open it again, at that moment the application crashed and does not let me open it anymore.

I am testing on my iphone 6s with iOS 13.1.3.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Try to find the device logs to get more information about that crash

Answer (score 0):

The [App Center SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/) work well for capturing crash information.  You can then see it in the [App Center Portal](https://appcenter.ms/)

Comment: I have just tested AppCenter, but it doesn't get me the crash

Answer (score 0):

I have already added AppCenter to the project, and now I can see the analytics, but it doesn't catch me crash error.

About the configuration of AppCenter, I have added to the AppDelegate.cs (FinishedLaunching)

```
AppCenter.Start("bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3a0",
                   typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
Crashes.NotifyUserConfirmation(UserConfirmation.AlwaysSend);

Crashes.SetEnabledAsync(true);
```

And to the App.xaml.cs

```
AppCenter.LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose;
AppCenter.Start("ios=b41cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0;" +
                  "uwp={Your UWP App secret here};" +
                  "android={Your Android App secret here}",
                  typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
Crashes.NotifyUserConfirmation(UserConfirmation.AlwaysSend);
```

I test the Crashes.GenerateTestCrash on the simulator and It works, but exaclty the iPhone crash no

Comment: I've never set the 'crashes.notifyuserconfirmation' or 'crashes.setanabledasync' and I've seen crash information from iPhones